# Imageai detector RuntimeWarning

Tags: python, tensorflow, imageai

> Resizing image in imageai-detector
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageai/Detection/Custom/**init**.py:1234:
> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
> return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))

I keep getting this warning, it seems like it has to do with this function inside **init.py**:

```
@staticmethod 
def _sigmoid(x):
    return 1./(1. + np.exp(-x))
```

Can we expect some updates of this module, or is it possible to fix it? Just ignore it?

> PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.0   tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1   keras==2.2.4

Comment: Can you properly explain what the problem is?, i mean what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a `detector = CustomObjectDetection()`, from **imageai.Detection.Custom**, which uses `detectObjectsFromImage` to make predictions on images (custom YoloV3 model, trained to detect license plates). The detector runs smoothly, but I keep getting this warning..

Answer (score 1):

This warning basically means the value returned by `np.exp(-x)` is larger than `float64` precision.

You can ignore this warning, since in Tensorflow model precision of `float64` is more than enough and `numpy` will handle the approximation.

However, you can still try with `np.float64` and then `np.float128` as `dtype` to check if the warning goes.

```
1./(1. + np.exp(-x, dtype=np.float128))
```